# What is this problem passing blocks in obj-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Xcode 11.4.1, IOS 13.3.1

Background: to get a graphical, stylized app up and running, I used `UIAlertController` extensively, knowing that someday, as the graphical design and artwork finalized, I would be replacing it with a custom class. That day has (partially) arrived, and migration to the custom class is available for some--but not all--of the instances of `UIAlertController`. In an effort to simplify the transition, I've built the custom class to have the same footprint/function calls but with a different style ENUM. Currently the custom class is subclassed from `UIAlertController` and makes decisions on whether to display the stock alert or the custom alert. Eventually, when all the custom alert graphics are available, I will remove the subclassing and the custom class will stand alone.

This is all working pretty much as intended, except I've run into a case of passing the `UIAlertAction` handler that crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

To start with, I defined the block as follows:

```
typedef void(^buttonActionHandler)();
```

Then I subclassed `UIAlertAction` and added a convenience variable to access the handler (since the handler seems to be hidden deep inside UIALertAction and not normally accessible).

```
@interface GoodAlertAction : UIAlertAction
{
}
    @property buttonActionHandler actionHandler;
@end
```

I added an override for `actionWithTitle` and this is where I see behavior I don't understand.

```
+(instancetype)actionWithTitle:(NSString *)title style:(GoodAlertActionStyleTypes)style handler:(void (^)(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull))handler
{

    if (style == UIAlertActionStyleDefault || style == UIAlertActionStyleCancel || style == UIAlertActionStyleDestructive)
    {
        //non-migrated alert; use standard UIAlertAction
        return (GoodAlertAction *) [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:title style:(UIAlertActionStyle) style handler:handler]
    }

    //migrated alert; use custom class
    GoodAlertAction action = [GoodAlertAction new];

    action.actionHandler = handler;
    action.actionHandler();     <--Successfully runs the handler. 

    buttonActionHandler testHandler = handler;
    testHandler();              <--Crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

As far as I can see, `action.actionHandler` and `testHandler` are defined the same. So, why does the former work and the latter crashes? That's the simplest form of the problem, but I actually uncovered it trying to pass the handler around later in the code.

**So the question is:**

1. What am I doing wrong/different with `testHandler` vs `action.actionHandler`?

Comment: @Rob you're probably right regarding the typedef. I'll experiment with that more tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m surprised that either works given that `handler` takes a parameter, whereas `buttonActionHandler` (which probably should be called `ButtonActionHandler` as a matter of convention) doesn’t.

So, you should define the `ButtonActionHandler` typedef to include the parameter:

```
typedef void(^ButtonActionHandler)(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action);
typedef UIAlertActionStyle GoodAlertActionStyle;

@interface GoodAlertAction: UIAlertAction
@property (copy) ButtonActionHandler actionHandler;
@end

@implementation GoodAlertAction

+ (instancetype)actionWithTitle:(NSString *)title style:(GoodAlertActionStyle)style handler:(ButtonActionHandler)handler
{
    if (style == UIAlertActionStyleDefault || style == UIAlertActionStyleCancel || style == UIAlertActionStyleDestructive)
    {
        //non-migrated alert; use standard UIAlertAction
        return (GoodAlertAction *) [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:title style:(UIAlertActionStyle) style handler:handler];
    }

    //migrated alert; use custom class
    GoodAlertAction *action = [GoodAlertAction new];

    action.actionHandler = handler;
    action.actionHandler(action);     // added parameter

    ButtonActionHandler testHandler = handler;
    testHandler(action);              // added parameter

    return action;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Rob's comment was the tip. I had forgotten to pass the argument to the handler, which is a `UIAction` Thus the following command worked properly:

```
 testHandler(action);
```

I can only assume that `action.actionHandler()` works without the argument because Apple still picks up the parent `action` even when the handler's argument is nil.